# Using a Database that i have copy in the Assets folder why the file "apk" its smaller then the actual Database

Tags: android

I have a database(17mb) that i copied in the assets folder and i am using it and everything working fine, now logicaly my apk file should minimum bigger but is not is only 7mb what i have done wrong?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Rename the apk file with zip extension, extract the files and check if your database is in there

Comment: You can simply open the .apk file with something like 7Zip and look, if your database is in there. If it is, be happy that it was compressed that much.

Comment: thanks it there!!, i am trying to find why my app work on my emulator working fine but not on my device i thought that could be in issue

Comment: You didn't mentioned, that the App doesn't work on your Device. I would also put the Database file in the 'res/raw'-folder. And what type of Database is this? Android has a build-in SQLite3 Database. Why don't you use that?

Comment: what do you mean with "could be an issue"? You haven't tried yet, or it's already failing?

Comment: @Lukas  its not a database that i build is a database that i get from a client and i just copy it to the asstes and using it in my app

Comment: @Mathias i already try and i have an issue i just thought that the issue could come from a problem of coping my database

Comment: The error that i get only on the device(HTC Desire): The application "name of app" has stopped unexpectedly.please try again

Comment: Ok, but that error is very general and you should check the logfile (adb logcat) for details, I doubt it has anything to do with the db size, if it's working elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An apk compresses all your project files, so it's normal that the apk is smaller than all files uncompressed. 7MB is usually not a problem on current Android devices out on the market, I also have app with an apk size of 25MB, and that also works fine on the device. btw: note that 25MB is the apk limit for APKs on the Android market, in case you decide to publish your app there some day.